# Finite State Machine / Android NDK JNI

Tags: c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Is it possible that i use Finite State Machine (http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa402a/slaa402a.pdf) on android. I already define some c files which works great but i cannot use this generated c files on android. Application works good on PC but doesn't on android.

Has anyone of you ever used it this together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete any older eclipse than juno. I work with JUNO now it's much better!

[What i did then](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin)